# Eclipse include spark packages Python

Tags: python, eclipse, apache-spark, pydev

I am using Spark and Python with Eclipse.

I need to include the same package: com.databricks:spark-avro_2.10:2.0.1

how can I do it in Eclipse?

Out of eclipse I run the code as following:

```
spark-submit --packages com.databricks:spark-avro_2.10:2.0.1 spark_sql.py
```

And it work. In Eclipse I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.avro. Please use Spark package http://spark-packages.org/package/databricks/spark-avro
```

However even using "http://spark-packages.org/package/databricks/spark-avro" the code does not run.

Thanks